# Calculate the area of a circle using a variation of the Triangle proof.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, area

Here's an example of the [Triangle proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle) showing the unwrapping of a circle to a triangle

[image: area]

Pause the animation at this intermediate shape consisting of a right angle triangle and a quarter circle

[image: assume]

The area of triangle is

$T$ = $\large \frac{1}{2}r \frac{3 \pi r}{2} = \frac{3 \pi r^2}{4}$

The area of the quarter circle is

$\large \frac{T}{3} = \frac{\pi r^2}{4}$

The total area of the shape is

$\large T + \frac{T}{3}$

Therefore

$\large \frac{3 \pi r^2}{4} + \frac{\pi r^2}{4} = \pi r^2$

Similarly for this shape

[image: shape1]

The area of triangle is

$T$ = $\large \frac{1}{2}r {\pi r} = \frac{\pi r^2}{2}$

The area of the semi circle is

$\large T = \frac{\pi r^2}{2}$

The total area of the shape is

$\large T + T$

Therefore

$\large \frac{\pi r^2}{2} + \frac{\pi r^2}{2} = \pi r^2$

Are those valid solutions?

Comment: From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Because of the symmetry of circles, "unwrapping part of the way" and doing some algebra at the end will give you the same result as "unwrapping all the way".  In fact this is true for any fraction of the circle that you unwrap.

Comment: I think calculating the area at any unwrapped fraction might not be that easy to solve. I chose two obvious shapes because the algebra was simple.

Comment: Except the whole exercise is pointless. There is real mathematics behind the animation, but the animation does not justify the mathematics. There are some glimmers of the justifications to be found in the animation, but I suspect they would be much harder to recognize for someone who doesn't already understand why the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$. And even if they did recognize them, figuring out how to turn those glimmers into an actual proof would still be incredibly difficult.